# Chartjs : Can I overwrite bar value on hover for every bar chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am using a simple bar chart from chartJS representing time passed (in seconds).
I was wondering if I could overwrite every bar's value to an array I could provide.
So instead of having 10983 I could write whatever I want, like 03:03:03 and another hh:mm:ss for the second bar and so forth.

Does anyone have an idea ?

Here is the chart I have so far
[image: Example]

```js
dataset = [{
    data: arrayData,
    backgroundColor : "#265d96" //#3e95cd //#265d96
  }];

  param = {
    type: "bar",
    data: {
      datasets: dataset,
      labels: arrayDesc
    },
    options: {
      responsive: true,
      maintainAspectRatio: true,
      scales: {
        yAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero:true
          }
        }]
      },
      legend: {
        display: false
      },
      tooltips: {
        enabled: true
      },
      animation: {
        animateScale: true,
        animateRotate: true
      },
      plugins:{
        labels:
        {
          render: () =>{},
          display : false
        }
      }
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a custom tooltip callback:

```js
tooltips: {
  callbacks: {
    label: (ttItem) => (new Date(ttItem.yLabel*1000).toISOString().substring(11, 19))
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for. I was trying callbacks but didn't know where to put it.